# I Can't get value from a function inside of other function shell script

Tags: shell, unix

I am trying to get the month as number with this function below:

```
get_month(){
    # Converter o mes para numeros para criacao de arquivo
    case "`date | awk '{print $2 }'`" in
        Jan) MON=01 ;;
        Feb) MON=02 ;;
        Mar) MON=03 ;;
        Apr) MON=04 ;;
        May) MON=05 ;;
        Jun) MON=06 ;;
        Jul) MON=07 ;;
        Aug) MON=08 ;;
        Sep) MON=09 ;;
        Oct) MON=10 ;;
        Nov) MON=11 ;;
        Dec) MON=12 ;;
    esac

    return $MON;
}
```

inside of second function below:

```
# Rotina de backup mensal
# Funcao para backup mensal dos arquivos
monthly_backup(){
    # Get month to create files that depending this info.
    get_month;
    cd /root/bkp/weekly

    if [[ $(date -d "-1 day" +%m) != $(date +%m) ]]; then
        zip /root/bkp/monthly/connectivity_$MON.zip  connectivity_* && rm -rf /root/bkp/weekly/connectivity_*
    else
        printf "Monthly nao rodara."
    fi

    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        printf '\e[92m Arquivos mensais zipados, e excluidos com sucesso \n'
    else
        printf '\e[92m Monthly Zip failed \n'
    fi
}
```

but when I call the function monthly_backup, my file is creating as: ***connectivity_*** instead of ***connectivity_01***, even if I run the get_month function before run monthly_backup.

But if I run the function  get_month directly on my terminal, I am able to run echo $MON and get the right value that it is 01, do you have any idea how can I handle that? probably it is not initializing, actually I have no idea. thanks!!

Comment: Why don't you use `MON=$(date '%d')` in `get_month()` ? Also, you will most likely want to capture the result of `get_month` in the calling function.

Comment: because I was trying to figure out how to get month as number not as Jan, Feb... and this function was all that I found, you saved 20 lines in just one!! haha Thank you @Corion

Comment: But is different for month: MON=$(date '+%m') anyway thanks :)

Comment: Duh, sorry - yes, `%m`, not `%d`. But you found that already :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use a function, don't give back the calculated results by setting a global variable. You did try a `return $MON`, but that would be a returnvalue (what you can see with `echo $?`) and should reflect success/some error.
Use `echo "$MON"` to return the result and `MON=$(get_month)`.

Using lowercase variable names and the shorter date option as shown in the comments, and you get

```
get_month() {
    # Converter o mes para numeros para criacao de arquivo
    local_mon=$(date '+%m')
    echo "${local_mon}"
}
# ....
# Rotina de backup mensal
# Funcao para backup mensal dos arquivos
monthly_backup(){
    # Get month to create files that depending this info.
    mon=$(get_month);
```